# How to autonumber table rows?

Tags: xml, xslt, xmltable

I want generate a column called "Position" and show the position of each driver (1, 2, 3) automatically. I try with `<xsl:number />` but just show the position in the XML and I don't want that. Any ideas?

XSLT CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd" />
    <xsl:template match="/grid">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
            <body>
                <table border="1" width="100%" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="5">Clasificación</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Piloto</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th>Imola</th>
                        <th>Monza</th>
                        <th>Silverstone</th>
                    </tr>               
                    <xsl:for-each select="driver">
                        <xsl:sort select="sum(points/*)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="name" /></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(points/*)" /></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="points/imola" /></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="points/monza" /></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="points/silverstone" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each> 
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML CODE:

```
<grid>
    <driver>
        <name>Driver A</name>
        <points>
            <imola>10</imola>
            <monza>2</monza>
            <silverstone>10</silverstone>
        </points>
    </driver>
    <driver>
        <name>Driver B</name>
        <points>
            <imola>9</imola>
            <monza>6</monza>
            <silverstone>7</silverstone>
        </points>
    </driver>
    <driver>
        <name>Driver C</name>
        <points>
            <imola>8</imola>
            <monza>10</monza>
            <silverstone>5</silverstone>
        </points>
    </driver>
</grid>
```

Comment: Please show a complete XSLT stylesheet that people can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what exactly you mean by "position". You can use either;

```
<xsl:value-of select="position()" />
```

or:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(../driver[sum(points/*) > sum(current()/points/*)]) + 1" />
```

The difference will be seen when two or more drivers have the same amount of points.

---

> The second one is perfect, but I don't understand how it works. Can
>   you explain it?

It counts the number of drivers that have more points than the current one.

- If the driver is in the first place, then there are no drivers that
  have more points - and the result is 0 (and we add 1 to that ==> 1st);
- If the driver is in the second place, then there is one driver that has more points - so the result is 1 (and we add 1 to that ==> 2nd);
- If two drivers are in the second place, then for both of them there is exactly one driver that has more points - so they are both in 2nd place;  the next driver has three drivers ahead of him, so he ends up being in 4th place - and no one is tagged as being 3rd.

Note that you could make this more efficient by storing the sum of points in a variable first, then use the variable in the two places in the table, e.g.:

```
<xsl:for-each select="driver">
    <xsl:sort select="sum(points/*)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
    <xsl:variable name="pts" select="sum(points/*)" />
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="count(../driver[sum(points/*) > $pts]) + 1" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="name" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="$pts" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="points/imola" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="points/monza" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="points/silverstone" /></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Unfortunately, it's not possible to avoid calculating the same thing separately for the sort.

Comment: The second one is perfect, but I don't understand how it works. Can you explain it? Thanks.

Comment: @Fran I have added a note to my answer.

Comment: With your explanation is very easy. Thanks again.